# How can I change Auto Correct table Options from Office.js API?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to disable the auto correct option for tables "Automatically Expand tables" (on Mac) or "Include new rows and columns in table" (on windows) from and Add-in build with Office.js api.
I saw that on VBscript you would use Application.AutoCorrect object , but I dod not find the same in Office.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I am sorry office.js currently do not provide API for accessing Automatically Expend Table Option, So would you please provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563 and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you for the fast response.